# How can I convert two series to Two Separate Columns of Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two series which is as follows :

[image]

How Can I convert this to

[image]

Comment: This is giving error: Cannot reset_index inplace on a Series to create a DataFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `reset_index`, make index column, and new index comes, i do "assign back" style, because `inplace=True` doesn't work for Series to Datarame stuff:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Gets as desired